# How to connect my web3 app only to Meta Mask wallet

Tags: javascript, web3js, metamask

I am trying to build an app with web3js. I use JavaScript for connecting the app to wallet.

```
const accounts = await web3.eth.requestAccounts().catch((error) => {
    $('#walletErrorMsg').html(error.message);
    $('#walletErrorModal').modal('show');
});
```

This is my code to connect app to wallet. This code works perfectly. But now I want to connect only with MetaMask. No support for other wallets. How can I connect only with meta mask ? Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate against `window.ethereum.isMetaMask`.

There is a high probabiliy of other wallets not setting this property and not returning `true`.

Docs: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-ismetamask

Comment: It returning true if only CoinBase wallet is installed